# Since when is the phone charging/discharging

Tags: java, android, battery

I wanted to learn more about the Android Services / Broadcasts, so I started a simple project, to create a battery monitoring app. It turned out pretty good, I'm using it for a few days now, but I want to add a new function: to show since when is the phone charging/discharging.

First I thought that I would create two static fields in my BoradcastReciever extension class, where I get and publish the data about the battery, one for the actual state (charging/discharging), and one for the time, when the change in state happened. This way, I could just subtract from the current time the last change, and know exactly since when is the phone charging/discharging.

But there is a problem with this solution: It won't show the correct data at first, when a user starts the app. I wouldn't make a big deal of it, but I saw that Android tracks this data somewhere, because inside my phone settings I found this information, so why take the hard way.

**So my question is:** *is there an easy way to get from the Android system the date/time (no matter what format) of the last charging state change?*

I looked at the [BatteryManager reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) but there are no constants named after what I seek, and which I could use, to get the information from the Intent of my receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android OS tracks the connect/disconnect of a power source, but does not make this data accessible to apps. You have to record this all yourself, using intent filters.

The two intent filters to use are `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`; with these, you can monitor when the power source is connected and disconnected.

You can find information about this process explained incredibly clearly [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html). Another blog describing the process can be found [here](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.de/2010/02/getting-battery-level-in-android-using.html).

Comment: Thank you, you were really quick! :) I'll accept your answer as soon, as Stackowerflow lets me.

Comment: No rush at all! Glad you got what you needed. :)

Comment: I didn't read your whole answer at first, i was so happy, i just focused on the intent names :D So you say, that i will have to monitor these changes by hand, and track the time, when they happened as i mentioned in the question?

Comment: Yup! And, when the app is first installed, you won't have any data, so you have to tell the user (very politely) to charge their phone to get the stats working properly.